# Which address space is occupied by the kernel in 64 bit Linux?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, x86-64

What is the address space of the kernel for 64 bit Linux, that is, what is the address range of the code, stack, heap and data segments used by it.

Comment: A nice thing about Linux is that you can actually download the source and look through it. The linker scripts might be a good place to start.

Answer (score 15):

On a 64-bit Linux all 64-bit addresses with the highest order bit set to 1 are reserved for the kernel. In other words, the top half of the virtual address space.

For full details see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64#Virtual_address_space_details

Comment: You mean half for 48 bit or 64 bit? Is it from 0xffffffff80000000 to 0xffffffffffffffff?

Comment: @ArneVogel That is what that wikipedia page I cited says, is that right?

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin: My comment was meant to address MetallicPriest's comment, sorry for the confusion. It would have been better to point out that anyone uncertain about the memory ranges should click the link.

Answer (score 2):

`PAGE_OFFSET` and `ULLONG_MAX` are constants with values that are equal to the start and end addresses of the kernel memory. You can use them directly in your kernel C module:

```
#define START_MEM   PAGE_OFFSET
#define END_MEM     ULLONG_MAX
```